How to pass parameter from parameterized parent view to parameterized child view?
I have two CDS-Views with the same Parameters. They have a composition - to parent association constellation.
The parent view will be used to build a Fiori List Report Page (via Elements). The composition view will provide data for the object page.
Problem:
I can't figure out how to pass the parameter from parent view to child view.
Can this be done on the CDS-View level?
See CDS-Views attached.
CDS-View1:
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'CDS1'
@Metadata.ignorePropagatedAnnotations: false
@Metadata.allowExtensions: true
@OData.publish: true
define root view entity C_VIEW1_Parameterized
  with parameters
    @Consumption.derivation: { lookupEntity: 'C_SglGregorianCalDateFunction',
      resultElement: 'DateFunctionStartDate', binding: [ {
        targetParameter: 'P_DateFunction', type: #PARAMETER, value : 'P_DateFunction' },
         { targetParameter : 'P_Language' , type : #SYSTEM_FIELD, value : '#SYSTEM_LANGUAGE'  } ]
      }
    @Consumption.hidden: true
    P_StartDate    : bedat,

    @Consumption.derivation: { lookupEntity: 'C_SglGregorianCalDateFunction',
    resultElement: 'DateFunctionEndDate', binding: [ {
      targetParameter: 'P_DateFunction', type: #PARAMETER, value : 'P_DateFunction' },
       { targetParameter : 'P_Language' , type : #SYSTEM_FIELD, value : '#SYSTEM_LANGUAGE'  } ]
    }
    @Consumption.hidden: true
    P_EndDate      : bedat,
    @Consumption.defaultValue: 'PREVIOUSYEARTODATE'
    @Consumption.valueHelpDefinition: [{
      entity: {
        name:'C_GregorianCalDateFuncVH',
        element:'DateFunction'
      }
    }]
    p_datefunction : datefunctionid
  as select from I_VIEW_PARAMETERIZED( P_StartDate: $parameters.P_StartDate , P_EndDate: $parameters.P_EndDate)
  composition of C_VIEW2_Parameterized as _cview2
{
  key variable1,
      variable2,
      variable3,
      _cview2  

}

CDS-View2:
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Test2'
@Metadata.ignorePropagatedAnnotations: true
@Metadata.allowExtensions: true
@OData.publish: true
define view entity C_VIEW2_PARAMETERIZED
  with parameters
    P_StartDate    : bedat,
    P_EndDate      : bedat
    p_datefunction : datefunctionid
  as select from I_View2_PARAMETERIZED ( P_StartDate: $parameters.P_StartDate, P_EndDate: $parameters.P_EndDate)
  association to parent C_VIEW1 as _cview1 on $projection.variable1 = _cview1.variable1

{

  key variable1,
  key variable2,
_cview1($parameters.P_EndDate, p_datefunction: $parameters.P_datefunction ).variable3,

      _cview1

}

Whenever I try to follow association from CDS-View1 to 2 i get the following error message:

I've already created the list report page in Fiori Elements - if it's not manageable on CDS-View lvl (with annotations) it should work via implementing a controller:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.core.tutorial.navigation/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.navigation.07/code
Any suggestions on the CDS-View level?
BRG Schoko
